# Two-dimensional plots for linear congruential generators

Tags: python, r, matlab, matplotlib, matlab-figure

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FAez.jpg]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
##General code for an lcg
lcg <- function(a, c, p, run.length, seed){
    x <- rep(0, run.length)
    x[1] <- seed
    for(i in 1:(run.length -1)){
        x[i+1] <- (a*x[i] +c) %% p
    }
    U <- x/p ##scale x to U(0,1)
    return(list(x=x, U=U))
}
z <- lcg(3,0,31,30,2)
z
x1 <- z$U[1:29]
x2 <- z$U[2:30]
plot(x1,x2, main="LCG[3,31]", xlab="U[i]",
   ylab="U[i-1]",col='blue', pch=1)
```

I want to have an overlapping plot with the negative slope red lines as shown on the image. How can i modify this code to add the red lines with negative slopes?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you want an R solution (I assume so, based on the (previous) title and the code you specified, but you have [python] [matlab] [matplotlib] [matlab-figure] tags ... ???)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the required intercept(s) and slope by trial and error: didn't think about the problem carefully enough to derive them from first principles ...  I don't think they're the same as the lines in your example, but presumably you can think a bit harder and figure what the slope and the sequence of intercepts should be ... ?

This works:

```
avec <- seq(0,1.2,by=0.1)
for (a in avec) {
   abline(a, b=-0.1, col=2)
}
```